# How does $t$-channel for electron-electron scattering in $g\psi\bar{\psi}$ exist?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams

Considering the Yukawa interaction $-g\phi\bar{\psi}\psi$ and $e^{-}e^{-} \rightarrow e^{-}e^{-}$ scattering, the 2nd order term in the numerator of the gell man low formula is

$\frac{(-ig)^2}{2!}$ <0|$T\psi\psi\bar{\psi}\bar{\psi}\psi\bar{\psi}\phi\psi\bar{\psi}\phi$|0>.

In order to get the $t$-channel diagram for the process, we’d have to contract a $\psi$ from an incoming particle to one of the $\bar{\psi}$ from the first vertex. However we’d need to contract the other $\psi$ from the incoming particle to the first vertex (otherwise we’d get the u channel diagram). But the only other fields to contract with are $\phi$ and $\psi$, which give 0 if I’m correct. So how does the t-channel for electron-electron scattering in this theory exist?

Comment: It's the Yukawa analogue of [Møller scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8ller_scattering) in QED. You get the same tree diagrams, namely a $t,u$ channel.

Comment: @knzhou still, how can you contract it to get the t-channel? Which contractions correspond to that? Each part of a Feynman diagram corresponds to a contraction, so you’d still have 2 spinor fields contracted to two other spinor fields with one being the same spinor field.

Comment: @LPZ I know, what I am asking is how to derive them from contractions.

Comment: Do you know how to derive the Feynman rules from contractions?

Comment: @LPZ yes, however I’m asking which contractions give the t channel

Answer (score 0):

The three channels are
[image]

Instead of looking for the t-channel you consider the s-channel. Which is indeed absent in this model.